# Object graph serialization in .NET and code version upgrades

Tags: .net, serialization

I need to serialize some object graphs to disc

What difficulties am I likely to encounter if I make changes to a class, then try to deserialize an old version?

Do some serializers handle this better than others?

What is the standard way of handling such a scenario?

For example, in a new version of the code, do I need to retain all the old classes so that when deserializing an old file i can do so to the old class, then migrate the data to the new class? Will changing the class' name/namespace break deserialization?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as I remember, the problems starts after:

- Adding a new field/property to a class;
- Changing the type of an existing field/property.

You can have [custom serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675.aspx) to handle versioning problems on you own.

But I would recommend to use [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) along with [Best Practices: Data Contract Versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733832.aspx) for the most common cases.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of depends upon what format you need the serialised data in.  If you use .NET 1.0 binary serialisation, then you'll be limited to a specific version of the DLL.  I wouldn't recommend that.

Personally I'd suggest using DataContracts with the default WCF serialiser: `DataContractSerialiser`.  You can control what happens when you deserialise a different version of the type with techniques like `[OnDeserializing]` and `IExtensibleDataObject`.

You can have `DataContractSerializer` output XML or binary too.